# Using lenses to view a Map as key-value pairs?

Tags: haskell, traversal, fold, lenses

The `traverse` lens (is it a lens?) allows looking at `Map key value` in a value-by-value basis. For example:

```hs
import Data.Map
import Control.Lens

simpleMap :: Map Int Char
simpleMap = fromList [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]

nextCharAll :: Map Int Char -> Map Int Char
nextCharAll = traverse %~ succ
```

`nextCharAll simpleMap` is `fromList [(1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`.

What kind of traversal/lens can I use to do something like the following?

```hs
nextIntNextChar :: Map Int Char -> Map Int Char
nextIntNextChar = 
    asKeyValuePairs 
    . (_key %~ (+1)) 
    . (_value %~ succ)
```

Comment: "is it a lens?" -- `traverse` is a traversal. Every lens is a traversal, but not every traversal is a lens. A traversal can reach zero or multiple targets, while a lens always reaches exactly one. If you want a catch-all term that works for traversals and lenses (and other things), you can use "optic".

Comment: Why are you want to do so tricky? You are already have the function from `Map` module `mapKeysWith` which  solve your problem. `nextIntNextChar = mapKeysWith succ succ`.

Comment: Moreover, in your case will be better (respect to performance) like this: `nextIntNextChar = fmap succ . mapKeysMonotonic succ`

Comment: This wouldn't be a lawful traversal, because if you were to do something like `(_key .~ 1)` this would map all the keys in the Map onto the same value, changing the number of elements, and violating the [traversal laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t:Traversal)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you like it, but one of the ways is to convert it to a list back and forth with `Iso`.

```
nextIntNextChar :: Map Int Char -> Map Int Char
nextIntNextChar = iso toList fromList . traverse %~ bimap (+1) succ
```

Comment: This does work, although it's worth realizing that this isn't a lawful isomorphism, because `toList . fromList $ [(1, '1'), (1, '2')]` isn't equal to `[(1, '1'), (1, '2')]`

Answer (score 2):

The `lens` package *does* provide a mechanism for dealing with keyed data structures, though it is suitable for operations that need *read* access to the keys, not for modifying the keys.  So, it would not help much with writing `nextIntNextChar` (see below), but you might find it useful for other operations that traverse key-value pairs.

This facility is provided by indexed optics from `Data.Lens.Indexed`.  Note that this is distinct from the `at` and `ix` operations from `Data.Lens.At`.  The latter allow you to focus on elements of a keyed data structure by index, while the former allow you to associate an "index" with a particular traversal or other optic that is carried along through lens operations and can be accessed or combined with other indexes as needed.

For example, if you wanted a lens operation to `succ` the `Char`s that are indexed by even `Int` keys, you could write:

```
succEvenChars :: Map Int Char -> Map Int Char
succEvenChars m = m & itraversed.indices even %~ succ
```

Here, `itraversed` constructs an indexed traversal of the `Map` using the `Int` keys as the index.  The `indices` optic selects the elements whose indices match a particular predicate.  The resulting indexed traversal can be used with a modification operation `%~` in the usual way.

(A warning:  using `traversed` in place of `itraversed` type checks but produces a different answer.  The `traversed` optic creates an indexed traversal as well, but the index is not the `Int` key from the map; it's an `Int` index that counts elements in traversal order starting from zero.  For this example, the first element, with even index 0 but having an odd-valued key of 1, is the one that has `succ` applied.)

Operations *are* provided to modify the *index*, but that's just a copy of the key, so modifying it doesn't rekey the original data structure  So, an implementation of `nextIntNextChar` that used indexed traversals wouldn't be very exciting.  Something like:

```
nextIntNextChar :: Map Int Char -> Map Int Char
nextIntNextChar m = fromList (m ^.. reindexed succ itraversed.to succ.withIndex)
```

This uses `itraversed` to construct an indexed traversal using the keys as indexes, applies `reindexed succ` to this indexed traversal to transform the indexes, uses the `to succ` optic to transform the values, and the `withIndex` optic to produce key-value pairs.  Viewing (`^..`) the resulting optic produces a list of new key-value pairs which can then be loaded up into a new map with `fromList`.  It's a `lens` solution, true, but it's not appreciably more readable or useful than the solutions provided in other answers and comments.

Note that indexed optics can have the index "loaded" from keys, but the index itself can hold just about anything, it doesn't need to be a key, and in particular doesn't need to uniquely specify a value.  As an example, if you have a `Tree` from `Data.Tree`, you can use `itraversed` to produce an indexed traversal using the "default key".  This key is a list of integer indexes giving a "path" through the tree, and so its length is the depth of the node.

Using `reindexed length` to reindex the traversal by depth, you can then perform traversals over all nodes at the same depth:

```
import Data.Tree
import Data.Tree.Lens
import Control.Lens

t1 :: Tree Char
t1 = Node 'a' [Node 'b' [Node 'c' [],Node 'd' []], Node 'e' [Node 'f' []], Node 'g' []]

main = do
  let nodesAt depth = reindexed length itraversed . index depth
      printTree = putStrLn . drawTree . fmap (:[])

  print $ t1 ^.. nodesAt 2           -- print nodes at depth 2
  printTree $ t1 & nodesAt 1 .~ 'x'  -- set nodes at depth 1
```